# Why am I getting errno: -4058 in VS Code when trying to deploy my react app?

Tags: reactjs, github, deployment

I added gh pages, added script but still it is showing some error. HELP !!

This is the initial part of the `package.json` file:

```
{
  "homepage": "https://aadii37.github.io/textutils-React",
  "name": "textutils",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "gh-pages": "^6.0.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.15.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

This is the error that keeps on showing when I type `npm run deploy`;
I added a build folder too before this

> textutils@0.1.0 deploy
> gh-pages -d build

```
node:events:492
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn git ENOENT
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:476:16)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:289:12)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:476:16)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn git',
  path: 'git',
  spawnargs: [ 'config', 'user.name' ]
}
```

I thought I would get a github prompt asking for my credentials but I didn't.

Also I have git and github desktop installed

Comment: Git works from the command line?